# Trying to add an enum into a 2D array properly

Tags: java, arrays, oop, enums

So I am trying to add a cellType into a 2D array. The input from the file looks like a 6x6 file where it can be any combination of the enum type in my enum class below. For some reason when I try to troubleshoot the program, only WALL is getting added into my 2D array. I'm thinking there might be an error in my where I am trying to iterate through the 2D array, but I can't see it.

Here is where I am trying to add it within my 2D  array

```
MazeCell.CellType[][] cell;
int rows = 6;
int cols = 6;
MazeCell.CellType cell2Add; 
while(inputFile.hasNext()) 
    {
        String mazeStart = inputFile.nextLine().trim();
        String [] mazeRowsAndCols = mazeStart.split(" ");
        //System.out.println(mazeStart);
        //System.out.println(mazeRowsAndCols[2]);
        MazeCell.CellType cell2Add; 
        for(int r = 1; r < rows+1; r++)
        {
            System.out.print(r-1); 
            for(int c = 1; c<cols+1; c++)
            {
                if(mazeRowsAndCols[r-1].equals("W"))
                {
                    cell2Add = MazeCell.CellType.WALL;
                }
                else if(mazeRowsAndCols[r-1].equals("M"))
                {
                    cell2Add = MazeCell.CellType.START;
                }
                else if (mazeRowsAndCols[r-1].equals("C"))
                {
                    cell2Add = MazeCell.CellType.END;
                }
                else if (mazeRowsAndCols[r-1].equals("O"))
                {
                    cell2Add = MazeCell.CellType.OPEN;
                }
                else if (mazeRowsAndCols[r-1].equals(" "))
                {
                    cell2Add = MazeCell.CellType.CURRENT_PATH;
                }
                else if (mazeRowsAndCols[r-1].equals("S"))
                {
                    cell2Add = MazeCell.CellType.END_FOUND;
                }
                else if (mazeRowsAndCols[r-1].equals("X"))
                {
                    cell2Add = MazeCell.CellType.REJECTED;
                }
                System.out.print(c);
                cell[r-1][c-1] = cell2Add;
            }
            System.out.println(); 
        }
        }
    }
    inputFile.close()
```

Here is my enum class.

```
public class MazeCell
{

public static enum CellType
{ 
    WALL("W"), START("M"), END("C"), OPEN("O"), CURRENT_PATH(" "), END_FOUND("S"), REJECTED("X");
    private final String display;
    private String type; 
    CellType(String display)
    {
        this.display = display;
    }

    public String getDisplay() { return display;}
    public void setType(String type){this.type = type;}
};
```

What the input file looks like:

```
  
W W W W W W  
 W W M W W W  
W W O O O W  
 W O W O O W  
W W C O O W  
 W W W W W W W  
W W W W W W
```

within cel[][] all I seem to be getting is Wall,

Comment: could you also provide the inputFile content?

Comment: You only parse the first line, for every line.

Comment: What happened to the old question, where I told you that splitting on `" "`  is a bad idea?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn why is it bad idea?

Comment: I don't see why splitting on " " is a bad idea? in fact it works perfectly when I print out the contents of each line. The problem is somewhere in my loop.

Comment: What do you get when you have `CURRENT_PATH` in your file?

Comment: Why would he? I thought input is well defined here.

Answer (score 0):

```
 (mazeRowsAndCols[r-1].equals("S"))
```

you are using OUTER index to iterate over INNER elements (input line length). Try

```
 (mazeRowsAndCols[c-1].equals("S"))
```

Moreover I would rather use `switch` for that (yes it is possible with string).

Besides I don't like the fact that you have outer `for` as this should be limited by input lines so `while` should be more then enough.

So in fact it should be something like that:

```
int row=0;
while(input.hasNext()){
String line=input.nextLine();
String parts[]=input.split(" ");

for(int c=0;c<parts.length;c++){
   element=parts[c];
   switch(element){
     case W: enumToAdd=WALL; break;
     case ......
    ///////////do the magic with `switch` here
   }
   maze[r][c]=enumToAdd;
}
row++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static CellType[][] read(Scanner scan) {
    final int totalRows = 6;
    final int totalColumns = 6;
    CellType[][] maze = new CellType[totalRows][totalColumns];

    for (int row = 0; row < totalRows; row++) {
        String line = scan.nextLine();

        for (int col = 0; col < totalColumns; col++)
            maze[row][col] = CellType.parseId(line.charAt(col));
    }

    return maze;
}

public enum CellType {
    WALL('W'),
    START('M'),
    END('C'),
    OPEN('O'),
    CURRENT_PATH(' '),
    END_FOUND('S'),
    REJECTED('X');

    private final char id;

    CellType(char id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public static CellType parseId(char id) {
        for (CellType type : values())
            if (type.id == id)
                return type;
        throw new EnumConstantNotPresentException(CellType.class, String.valueOf(id));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a few changes to make this a little easier to reason about.

First, let's fix up cell type a little to make it easier to use:

1. We should add a `static` `fromDisplay(String s)` method.
2. We should probably remove `setType`, because any call to `setType` will set that variable for that enum value **everwhere**, as there is only ever one instance of an enum value.

The resultant code is

```
public class MazeCell
{

public static enum CellType
{ 
    WALL("W"),
    START("M"),
    END("C"),
    OPEN("O"),
    CURRENT_PATH(" "),
    END_FOUND("S"),
    REJECTED("X");

    static {
        final Map<String, CellType> fDisplay = new HashMap<>();
        for(final CellType c : CellType.values()) {
            fDisplay.put(c.display, c);
        }
        fromDisplay = fDisplay;
    }

    private static final Map<String, CellType> fromDisplay;

    private final String display;

    CellType(String display)
    {
        this.display = display;
    }

    public String getDisplay() { return display; }

    public static CellType fromDisplay(final String display) {
        return fromDisplay.getOrDefault(display, REJECTED);
    }
}
}
```

Now, let's fix up the code. The problem is, as pointed out, that you only parse the first line every time. Let's fix that and clean up the code a little, too.

```
// Read our input in a try-with-resources
try(final File file = ...) {
    final Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
    // initialize the array
    final MazeCell.CellType[][] cells = new MazeCell.CellType[6][6];

    // assuming there are 6 rows
    for(int r=0; r<6; r++) {
        if(!input.hasNext()) throw new RuntimeException("Input file does not match our expectations! Only " + (r) + " lines!");

        // assuming the columns are separated by spaces
        final String[] cols = input.nextLine().trim().split(" ");
        if(cols.length != 6) throw new RuntimeException("Input file does not match our expectations! Row " + (r + 1) + " had " + cols.length + " columns!");

        for(int c=0; c<6; c++) {
            cells[r][c] = MazeCell.CellType.fromDisplay(cols[c]);
        }
    }

    // print it out or whatever
    Arrays.stream(cells).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

That should do it. Hope this helps!

Comment: `static {
        fromDisplay = new HashMap<>();
        for(final CellType c : CellType.values()) {
            fromDisplay.put(c.display, c);
        }
    }` - **THIS IS USELESS FOR ENUMS WITH LESS THAN 10k CONSTANTS**

Comment: From my testing, my approach is about 10% faster with a warm JVM and the same number of enum constants. Oleg's is slightly faster with a cool JVM and the same number of enum constants.

Comment: Where is test code? Your test is wrong. 10%+ only using Map for small data is impossible!

Comment: https://gist.github.com/napentathol/44a9f208c566c9c3db700a4a8fd937cf

I consistently get ~1,400,000,000ns for the first run of my approach. ~1,200,000,000ns for subsequent runs. And, ~1,300,000,000ns for runs of your approach. You are right, though, the test does not account for run time of the loop, securerandom, or access times.